# How to use Perl's qx mv file to directory?

Tags: perl

I want to move dedicated files to a subfolder of their current folder. This work (with one dedicated file):

```perl
qx/mv -v 'the name of the file' TRANS/; # TRANS is the subfolder at the same level as 'my file'
```

But the following doesn't work:

```perl
while (defined($_ = <PODCASTS>)) {
   if (/ \d{1}\.mp3$/) {
       print $_;
       qx/mv -f -v "$_" TRANS/;
       die; # for testing on first occurrence
   };
}
```

Which gives (`Ariane ...Tadjikistan 1.mp3` being the actual name of the file):

```
mv: rename Ariane Zevaco autour des Musiciens populaires au Tadjikistan 1.mp3
    to TRANS/Ariane Zevaco autour des Musiciens populaires au Tadjikistan 1.mp3: No such file or directory
```

I used many quoting variations with no avail (giving various error comments).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to commandline with directories having spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608574/passing-arguments-to-commandline-with-directories-having-spaces)

Comment: Why are you not just using the `rename` function built into Perl?

Comment: Using `move` from the core [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) module is another option.

Comment: Yes, "That's solved my problem" ! The chomp was essential - didn't noticed the requirement at first. Thanks so much for the relief. Have to think a lot around this.

Answer (score 4):

The immediate problem is that you don't remove that trailing line feed from the lines you read from the file handle.

That said, don't rely on shell parsing and instead use the safe way of passing parameters unmodified to the called program:

```perl
system(qw(mv -f -v --), $_, 'TRANS/');
```

**NOTE:** you are passing the whole line to the command, which will include the line ending. You should `chomp` the line first.

To quote [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html):

> `system LIST`
>
> ... If there is more than one argument in LIST,
>               or if LIST is an array with more than one value, starts the
>               program given by the first element of the list with arguments
>               given by the rest of the list.

In C language terms the `main()` function of the program will be called with `argc == 4` and `argv[2]` will receive the contents of `$_` from your Perl script.

---

**Alternative solution**

For this simple problem you don't really need the shell. You could simply use the Perl [`rename()` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html)

---

**BONUS CODE** I would suggest to rewrite your code to be more Perl-idiomatic:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw(:sys_wait_h);

while (<PODCASTS>) {
   if (/ \d\.mp3$/) {
       chomp;
       print "$_\n";
       system(qw(mv -f -v --), $_, 'TRANS/');
       die "Can't execute \"mv\": $!\n"
           if $? < 0;
       die '"mv" killed by signal '  . WTERMSIG($?)    . "\n"
           if WIFSIGNALED($?);
       die '"mv" exited with error ' . WEXITSTATUS($?) . "\n"
           if WEXITSTATUS($?);
   }
}
```

**BONUS CODE 2** how to replace the `system('mv', ...)` with Perl builtin functions:

```perl
   my $target = "TRANS/$_";

   # Emulate the "mv -f" option
   unlink($target) || $!{ENOENT}
       or die "unlink: $!\n";

   # same as "mv"
   rename($_, $target)
       or die "rename: $!\n";
```

Comment: 1) perlfunc recalls me the general subject of variable number of arguments (somewhere in other languages) - just remembering...

Comment: You buried the lede. A `chomp` call is sufficient to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: 2) The aim is to remove duplicates I find in my iTunes Podcast folders: after renaming, I would have to delete the original file... Well, move is a rename which is king of move : why a move ? Anyway .

Comment: @ mob noticed this to be very, very important - could be essential, as you said. Thx.

Comment: @ Shawn Will investigate. Thx.

Comment: Avoiding the shell is also very important in case one of your files happens to have a shell metacharacter other than a space.

Comment: @fr6 Your comment makes no sense. [rename](https://perldoc.pl/functions/rename) is the same as move, it does not leave the "original file".

Comment: @fr6 I've added example code to replace the `system()`.